# Why TypeScript not checking for null in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript

I have an interesting problem. Here's the code:

```js
type Person = {
  name: string | null,
  age: number | null,
  contacts: {
    phone: number | null,
    email: string | null
  } | null
}

const emptyPerson: Person = {
  name: null,
  age: null,
  contacts: null
}

// should warn that `contacts` can be `null`, but it's not
console.log(emptyPerson.contacts.email)
```

Seems like TS is narrowing type, but why?
[image]

I tried same piece of code in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and it worked just fine.

So my question is why TS dropping out `null` and how to prevent this strange behavior?

Comment: Do you have `strictNullChecks` or `strict` enabled in your project? [Playground with the setting disabled](https://tsplay.dev/wgQyvm)

Answer (score 0):

As VLAZ commented, the problem was in `strictNullChecks` option.
Setting it to `true` solved the problem.